# What is wrong with my JSON?

Tags: json

{
    “id”: 0,
    “isfname”: null,
    “islname”: null,
    “csfname”: null,
    “cslname”: null,
    “snf”: null,
    “dateadmit”: null,
    “csaddress”: null,
    “cscsz”: null,
    “cstelephone”: null,
    “csemail”: null,
    “datemaneed”: null,
    “csownrent”: null,
    “csage”: 0,
    “isage”: 0,
    “isincome”: [
        {
            “type”: null,
            “gross”: 0,
            “deducts”: 0,
            “net”: 0
        }
    ],
    “csincome”: [
        {
            “type”: null,
            “gross”: 0,
            “deducts”: 0,
            “net”: 0
        }
    ],
    “banks”: [
        {
            “type”: null,
            “desc”: null,
            “owner”: null,
            “amt”: 0
        }
    ],
    “inv”: [
        {
            “type”: null,
            “desc”: null,
            “owner”: null,
            “amt”: 0
        }
    ],
    “csira”: 0,
    “isira”: 0,
    “csli”: [
        {
            “type”: null,
            “desc”: null,
            “cv”: 0,
            “fv”: 0
        }
    ],
    “isli”: [
        {
            “type”: null,
            “desc”: null,
            “cv”: 0,
            “fv”: 0
        }
    ],
    “veh”: [
        {
            “type”: null,
            “makemodel”: null,
            “amt”: 0
        }
    ],
    “realty”: [
        {
            “desc”: null,
            “home”: true,
            “amt”: 0
        }
    ],
    “totals”: [
        {
            “banks”: 0,
            “inv”: 0,
            “csli”: 0,
            “isli”: 0,
            “veh”: 0,
            “realty”: 0,
            “exemptli”: 0,
            “exemptira”: 0,
            “exempthome”: 0,
            “totalgross”: 0,
            “totalexempt”: 0,
            “totalcountable”: 0,
            “csra”: 0,
            “isretained”: 0,
            “totalretained”: 0,
            “totalspenddown”: 0
        }
    ],
    “shelters”: {
        “rent”: 0,
        “mortgage”: 0,
        “retaxes”: 0,
        “hoins”: 0,
        “sua”: 0,
        “shelterstd”: 0
    },
    “ismedins”: 0,
    “isincavail”: 0,
    “isinctosnf”: 0,
    “isinctocs”: 0,
    “spenddown”: {
        “snfbill”: 0,
        “legal”: 0,
        “mortgage”: 0,
        “ppf”: 0,
        “newvehicle”: 0,
        “repairs”: 0
    },
    “otherspenddown”: [
        {
            “annuity”: 0,
            “other”: null
        }
    ],
    “manos”: {
        “minmmna”: 0,
        “maxmmna”: 0,
        “mincsra”: 0,
        “maxcsra”: 0,
        “pna”: 0,
        “incomelimit”: 0
    }
}

Comment: Why do you believe there is something wrong with it? Does it contain the wrong data, for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quotes are all wrong:

```
“islname”
```

Should be

```
"islname"
```

Did you copy it from MS Word document or something? Don't do that.

Answer (score 0):

according to JSON parser: Unrecognized token '?'

http://json.parser.online.fr

Bad quotes.